# Higher order derivative of exponential map

Tags: lie-algebras, matrix-exponential

The derivative of the exponential map is given by ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map#Statement)):

$$
\frac{d}{dt} e^{X(t)} = e^{X(t)} \frac{1 - e^{-ad_{X(t)}}}{ad_{X(t)}} \frac{d}{dt}X(t)
$$

Is there a reasonable formula for higher order derivatives:
$$
\frac{d^n}{dt^n} e^{X(t)} = ??
$$

Or more ideally:
$$
\frac{d}{dt_1}\dots\frac{d}{dt_n} e^{X(t_1, \dots, t_n)} = ??
$$

I have tried the [direct formal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map#A_direct_formal_argument) from wiki for $t_1, t_2$ but got lost in it pretty quickly.

Comment: I am familiar with ${d  \over dt}e^{X(t)}=\int _0^1 ds e^{(1-s)X(t)}{d  \over dt}X(t) e^{sX(t)}$ which is easy to generalize

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying but I would like, at least, reduce it to one integral. Direct application results in n integrals for n-th derivative.

Comment: of course. It is the Dyson Series.

Comment: Never heard of Dyson series, by looking at the wiki articles it is not obvious to me at all that it is directly related.

Comment: It is a special case, where $A(t)=D+B(t)$ but even there you typically need the multiple integrals.