# $n$-th derivative of $e^{Y(\delta,t)}$ at at $\delta=0$ for a special $Y(\delta,t)$

Tags: matrix-exponential

Posting again to get better traction.

I am looking for a representation of the expression:

$$
\frac{\partial^n} {\partial\delta^n} e^{Y(\delta,t)},
$$

where $Y(\delta,t) : \mathbb R^2_+ \rightarrow \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ an smooth function matrix-valued function such that $Y(0,t) = 0$, the zero matrix for all $t$. $Y(\delta,t)$ assumes the form:

$$
Y(\delta,t) = \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^M E_{ij} t^i \delta^j
$$

where each $E_{i,j}$ is a time-independent matrix. I am aware of the integral representation of the first derivative:

$$
\frac{\partial} {\partial \delta} e^{Y(\delta,t)}
=
\int_{0}^1 d s_1 \; e^{s_1 Y(\delta,t)} \frac{\partial Y(\delta,t))}{\partial \delta} e^{(1-s_1)Y(\delta,t)}
$$

I am interested in a similar integral representation for $\frac{\partial^n} {\partial \delta^n} e^{Y(\delta,t)}$. I tried differentiating under the integral sign and using the integral representation above, but I couldn't see a pattern for what the formula for the $n$-th derivative would be? Can someone help or point to references?

Similar question discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4454084/higher-order-derivative-of-exponential-map).

I differentiated under the integral sign to to obtain the second derivative. Note I am only interested in second (and higher derivatives) evaluated at $\delta = 0$. I've also updated notation above.

Is this correct? I tried differentiating  under integral sign again to obtain third derivative evalauted at $\delta = 0$, but I couldn't see an obvious pattern that generalizes to arbitrary $n$-th derivative. **I can add my computation for the third derivative later on.**

Differentiating under the integral sign
we can compute the second, partial derivative with respect to $\delta$ as well. We get:

\begin{align}
        \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \delta^2} \exp(Y(\delta, t)) 
        & =
        \int_0^1 ds_1 
        \frac{\partial}{\partial \delta}
        \Bigg (
        e^{s_1Y(\delta, t)} \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta} e^{(1-s_1)Y(\delta, t)}
        \Bigg ), \\
        & = 
        \int_0^1 ds_1 
        \Bigg (  \frac{\partial}{\partial \delta} e^{s_1Y(\delta, t)} \Bigg )
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta} e^{(1-s_1)Y(\delta, t)},
        \\
        & +
        \int_0^1 ds_1 
        e^{s_1Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial^2 Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta^2} 
        e^{(1-s_1)Y(\delta, t)}, \\
        & +
        \int_0^1 ds_1 
        e^{s_1Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta} 
        \Bigg ( \frac{\partial}{\partial \delta} e^{(1-s_1)Y(\delta, t)} \Bigg ),
        \\
        & := I_1(\delta,t) + I_2(\delta,t) + I_3(\delta,t).
    \end{align}

Let's analyze each term within the integral one by one:

\begin{align}
       I_1(\delta,t) & = 
       \int_0^1
       \int_0^1 
       ds_1 ds_2 \; s_1
        e^{s_1 s_2Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta}
        e^{s_1(1-s_2)Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta} e^{(1-s_1)Y(\delta, t)},
        \\
        I_2(\delta,t) & =
        \int_0^1 ds_1 
        e^{s_1Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial^2 Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta^2} 
        e^{(1-s_1)Y(\delta, t)}, \\
        I_3(\delta,t) & =
        \int_0^1 \int_0^1 ds_1 ds_2 \; (1-s_1)
        e^{s_1Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta} 
        e^{(1-s_1) s_2  Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta}
        e^{(1-s_1)(1-s_2) Y(\delta, t)}.
   \end{align}

However, since we are interested in evaluating,
\begin{equation}
       \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \delta^2} \exp(Y(\delta, t)) \Bigg |_{\delta = 0},
   \end{equation}
using that $Y(0,t) = 0$,
the terms $I_1, I_2, I_3$ simply to:

\begin{align}
       I_1 (0,t) & = 
       \int_0^1
       \int_0^1 
       ds_1 ds_2 s_1
        \Bigg ( \frac{\partial Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta} \Bigg )^2
        = 
        \frac{1}{2}
        \Bigg ( \frac{\partial Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta} \Bigg )^2
        ,
        \\
        I_2(0,t) & =
        \int_0^1 ds_1 
        \frac{\partial^2 Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta^2}
        = 
        \frac{\partial^2 Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta^2} 
        , \\
        I_3 (0,t) & =
        \int_0^1 \int_0^1 ds_1 ds_2 \;
        (1-s_1)
        \Bigg ( \frac{\partial Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta} \Bigg )^2
        =
        \frac{1}{2}
        \Bigg ( \frac{\partial Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta} \Bigg )^2
   \end{align}

Therefore, we have:

\begin{align}
       \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \delta^2} \exp(Y(\delta, t)) \Bigg |_{\delta=0}
       =
       \Bigg ( \frac{\partial Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta} \Bigg )^2
       +
       \frac{\partial^2 Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta^2}.
       \end{align}

Some computations for the third derivative. Any chance I'm on the right track? If so, can anyone help me spot a pattern for the $n$-th derivative evaluated at $\delta = 0$.

Similarly,

\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial^3}{\partial \delta^3} \exp(Y(\delta, t))
    =
    \frac{\partial}{\partial \delta} 
    I_1(\delta,t) +
    \frac{\partial}{\partial \delta}  I_2(\delta,t) +
    \frac{\partial}{\partial \delta} I_3(\delta,t)
    :=
    F_1(\delta,t) 
    +
    F_2(\delta,t) 
    +
    F_3(\delta,t).
    \end{equation}

\vspace{0.1in}

Writing the double and triple integrals as,

\begin{equation}
        \int_0^1
        \int_0^1 
        ds_1 ds_2
        =
        \int_{[0,1]^2}
        ds
        \quad \quad 
        \int_0^1
        \int_0^1 
        \int_0^1
        ds_1 ds_2 ds_3
        =
        \int_{[0,1]^3}
        ds
    \end{equation}

we compute each of the terms above one by one:

\begin{align}
        F_1(\delta,t) & =
        \int_{[0,1]^3}
        ds \;
        s^2_1s_2
        e^{s_1 s_2 s_3 Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta}
        e^{s_1 s_2 (1-s_3) Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta}
        e^{s_1(1-s_2)Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta} e^{(1-s_1)Y(\delta, t))}, \\
        & +
        \int_{[0,1]^3}
        ds \;
        s^2_1(1-s_2)
        e^{s_1 s_2Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta}
        e^{s_1(1-s_2) s_3Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta}
        e^{s_1(1-s_2) (1-s_3) Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta} e^{(1-s_1)Y(\delta, t))}, \\
    & + 
    \int_{[0,1]^3}
        ds \;
        s_1(1-s_1)
        e^{s_1 s_2Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta}
        e^{s_1(1-s_2)Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta} e^{(1-s_1) s_3 Y(\delta, t))}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta}
        e^{(1-s_1) (1-s_3) Y(\delta, t))}, \\
    & + \int_{[0,1]^2}
        ds \;
        s_1
        e^{s_1 s_2Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial^2 Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta^2}
        e^{s_1(1-s_2)Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta} e^{(1-s_1)Y(\delta, t))}, \\
        & +
        \int_{[0,1]^2}
        ds \;
        s_1
        e^{s_1 s_2Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta}
        e^{s_1(1-s_2)Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial^2 Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta^2} e^{(1-s_1)Y(\delta, t))}.
    \end{align}

Evaluating at $\delta = 0$ yields,

\begin{align}
    F_1(0,t)
    & =
    \int_{[0,1]^3}
        ds \;
        s^2_1s_2
        \bigg ( \frac{\partial Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta} \bigg )^3
    +
    \int_{[0,1]^3}
        ds \;
        s^2_1(1-s_2)
        \bigg ( \frac{\partial Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta} \bigg )^3
    +
    \int_{[0,1]^3}
        ds \;
        s_1(1-s_1)
        \bigg ( \frac{\partial Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta} \bigg )^3, \\
    & + \int_{[0,1]^2}
        ds \; s_1
        \frac{\partial^2 Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta^2}
        \frac{\partial Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta} 
    + \int_{[0,1]^2}
        ds \; s_1
        \frac{\partial^2 Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta^2}
        \frac{\partial Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta}.
\end{align}
\begin{align}
    F_2(\delta,t) & = \int_{[0,1]^2} ds \;
    s_1
    e^{s_1 s_2 Y(\delta, t)}
    \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta}
    e^{s_1 (1-s_2) Y(\delta, t)}
    \frac{\partial^2 Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta^2} e^{(1-s_1)Y(\delta, t)}, \\
    & +
    \int_{[0,1]^2} ds
        (1-s_1)
        e^{s_1Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial^2 Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta^2} 
        e^{(1-s_1) s_2 Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta}
        e^{(1-s_1) (1-s_2) Y(\delta, t)}, \\
    & + 
    \int_{[0,1]} ds 
        e^{s_1Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial^3 Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta^3} 
        e^{(1-s_1)Y(\delta, t)}
\end{align}

Evaluating at $\delta = 0$ yields,

\begin{align}
    F_2(0,t) & = 
    \int_{[0,1]^2} ds \;
    s_1
    \frac{\partial Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta}
    \frac{\partial^2 Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta^2}
    + \int_{[0,1]^2} ds
        (1-s_1)
        \frac{\partial^2 Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta^2} 
        \frac{\partial Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta}
    + \int_{[0,1]} ds 
        \frac{\partial^3 Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta^3} 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
    F_3(\delta,t) & = 
    \int_{[0,1]^3} ds \;
        (1-s_1) s_2
        e^{s_1 s_3 Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta}
        e^{s_1 (1-s_3) Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta} 
        e^{s_2 (1-s_1)Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta}
        e^{(1-s_2)(1-s_1)Y(\delta, t))}, \\
    & +
    \int_{[0,1]^3} ds \;
        s_2(1-s_1)
        e^{s_1Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta} 
        e^{s_2 (1-s_1) s_3 Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta}
        e^{s_2 (1-s_1) (1-s_3) Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta}
        e^{(1-s_2)(1-s_1)Y(\delta, t))}, \\
    & + \int_{[0,1]^3} ds \;
        (1-s_2)(1-s_1)^2
        e^{s_1Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta} 
        e^{s_2 (1-s_1)Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta}
        e^{(1-s_2)(1-s_1)Y(\delta, t))}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta}
        e^{(1-s_2)(1-s_1)s_3Y(\delta, t))}, \\
    & + \int_{[0,1]^2} ds \;
        (1-s_1)
        e^{s_1Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial^2 Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta^2} 
        e^{s_2 (1-s_1)Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta}
        e^{(1-s_2)(1-s_1)Y(\delta, t))}, \\
    & + \int_{[0,1]^2} ds \;
        (1-s_1)
        e^{s_1Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta} 
        e^{s_2 (1-s_1)Y(\delta, t)}
        \frac{\partial^2 Y( \delta, t)}{\partial \delta^2}
        e^{(1-s_2)(1-s_1)Y(\delta, t))}
\end{align}

Evaluating at $\delta = 0$ yields,

\begin{align}
    F_3(0,t) & = 
    \int_{[0,1]^3} ds \;
        (1-s_1) s_2
        \bigg ( \frac{\partial Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta} \bigg )^3
    + \int_{[0,1]^3} ds \;
        s_2(1-s_1)
        \bigg ( \frac{\partial Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta} \bigg )^3
    + \int_{[0,1]^3} ds \;
        (1-s_2)(1-s_1)^2
        \bigg ( \frac{\partial Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta} \bigg )^3, \\
    & + \int_{[0,1]^2} ds \;
        (1-s_1)
        \frac{\partial^2 Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta^2} 
        \frac{\partial Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta}
    + \int_{[0,1]^2} ds \;
        (1-s_1)
        \frac{\partial Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta} 
        \frac{\partial^2 Y( 0, t)}{\partial \delta^2}.
\end{align}